# Best solution for getting {id} from url?

Tags: vue.js, django-models, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create a feature where individuals can create Listings, and other users can submit an application. ATM I can't quite figure out how to get the ID from the URL of:

'http://localhost:3000/listings/2/'

I have a hunch that this needs Vue router and $route.params.id? Basically I want in my form.listing the ID of the listing in which users are applying to. In this case it would be '2'

**My folder structure is .../listings/_id/index.vue**

This is my backend for the user_applications model in DRF:

```
 listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="1")
```

Here's the frontend: I was hoping I could use the props value in script, but it seems like it only works in template, oh well.

```
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      role: null,
      company: null,
      status: "Pending"
      // listing: listings.id
    }
  }),

  props: ["listings"],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loggedInUser"])
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$axios
        .post("/api/v1/apps/", this.form)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's as easy as `this.$route.params.id`. You can invoke `$route.params.id` directly in your template, without using `this`. **Don't use arrow functions in your component, though!** They strip out the value of `this`! Also, all props and data attributes are available on `this` as well. So `this.listing` and `this.$route` are available, not only in your template, but in your Vue component's methods and computed properties, as well.

Try this approach, instead:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        role: null,
        company: null,
        status: "Pending",
        listing: this.listings.id
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Oh awesome! thanks for pointing out the arrow function concept, I just read more about that and it clears up some confusion I had in the past. So essentially, this.$route.params.id works as it comes as part of due, and this.listings.id works bc of my props right? Also you forgot to warp form: {} inside of return{}

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track when thinking of using `VueRouter`. Lets say that your component name is `Listing`.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Listing form './path/to/ListingComponent.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/listing/:id',
      component: Listing,
      // return parms.id as listingId for the `Listing` component.
      props: route => ({ listingId: route.params.id })
    }
  ]
})
```

In this way you have `listingId` passed to the `props` of `Listing`.